# CoreDataでattribute表示

Tags: swift, swiftui, coredata

CoreDataで

EntityをAData、attributeを adataとし、Listで adataを表示したいのですが、初期値が空のためか、items.adataが見つからない

と出ます

items.adata?

としても、出ます。

なにが必要ですか？

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \AData.adata, ascending: true)],
       animation: .default
    ) private var items: FetchedResults<AData>
    
    var body: some View {
         NavigationView {
             List {
                 Section {
                    ForEach(0 ..< items.adata.count) {
                        Text(items.adata[index])
                    }
             )
             }
        } header: {
            Text("dust")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

手元に確認環境がないので想像ですが、

```
ForEach(0 ..< items.count) { index in Text(items[index].adata) }
```

になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。items.countは通りました。ですが、items[index].adataはExpected member name following '.' のエラーメッセージが出ます。adataは配列で、配列は他にあと２つあるのですが、それらもitems.countでいいでしょうか。差異をつけることは可能ですか。

Comment: ADataの構造がわからないため的確なコメントはできませんが、adataはアトリビュートではなくリレーション(他のエンティティを参照)ということでしょうか。もしくは、配列をバイナリなどに変換しているのでしょうか。いずれにせよText()に配列を渡すことはできないので、adataの各要素ごとにText()を使う必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。adataは配列でbinary dataとして設定しています。（配列の設定の仕方がこれしか分かりません）adataの各要素ごとにText()ということは、無数の配列内容の保存には無数のText()が必要になるのでしょうか。

Comment: adataを配列に戻し、その配列に対してForEach(中略) {index in Text(中略) }を行います。ただ、items自体が配列なので、何をどのように表示させたいのかをご検討ください。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

全体のコードがコンパイルが通らないように思えます。

ForEachの部分を以下のようにすることでうまくと思います。

```swift
ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
  let string = item.adata //ここでData(Binary Data)から配列に変換する処理が必要
  Text(string)
}
```